# SQLPlus prevent column from being padded to its column name's length

Tags: sqlplus

I have a query that I need formatted in a particular way, but when I have an 8-character string with a 12-character column name, it pads the column to 12 characters even with Set Heading Off and Set Pagesize 0.  Is there a way to display a column such that it will not include the length of the column name when calculating the width to use?

This is not the same as "SQLPlus varchar2 outputs whitespaces", which does not appear to be asking about the case when the column name is longer than the data name - just when the data appears to have an excessive length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLPlus varchar2 outputs whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619463/sqlplus-varchar2-outputs-whitespaces)

Comment: The above links strongly appears to be an answer to your question.  The short answer is, no, there is nothing you can directly do about it, but there are a number of workarounds.